# TextInput secureTextEntry={true} is not working (React Native}

Tags: react-native

This is my code:

```
<TextInput
    style={styles.inputs}
    placeholder={'Password'}
    value={password}
    onChangeText={setPassword}
    multiline={true}
    textContentType="default"
    secureTextEntry={true}
/>
```

secureTextEntry={true} should be causing the text to turn into dots as the user is typing, but it shows the text. Am I doing something wrong? I want the password text to be hidden / turned into dots as the user is typing his password.

Comment: Having the same issue. I tried the accepted answer. Didn't help. :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`secureTextEntry={true}` won't work when `multiline` props is enabled (true). Check this https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#securetextentry

Please remove it and try